# cvs update - what is updated

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs

We're new to CVS.
We have a branch named br_X.
We co the branch to a working directory on our linux box.
We perform cvs status to make sure we're in the branch.

```
File: file.c  Status: Up-to-date
   Working revision:    1.1     Mon May 19 19:51:28 2014
   Repository revision: 1.1     /nfs/src/file.c,v
   Sticky Tag:          br_X (branch: 1.1.104)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      -kk
```

We perform a code sync from the trunk to this branch br_X.
After cvs commit from the code merges from trunk to br_X, we like to perform a cvs update.
From reading the manual, we are still unsure if the cvs update would update all changes from the Trunk HEAD or would the command simply updates on br_X alone.

On the branch working directory, do we simply use command

```
cvs update
```

OR

```
cvs update -r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a branch checked out, an `update` by itself will always retrieve the latest revisions from that branch, so this is the option you want.

Adding `-r <something>` will retrieve the latest revisions from some other branch/tag.

As an aside, I recommend setting up another CVS module where you can experiment with various cvs command to see what they do without risking damage to your main codebase. eg. I have a `cvstest` module that I encourage my colleagues to use.